# RegExp differs from using a simple regex literal

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to lift properties from a string like this:

```
var valueAccessor = "function (){return { id:'someId',label:'Some Label',value:PropertyOnModel} }";
```

This works when I specifically want to get `value` from the above `string`, specifically using this code:

```
var value = valueAccessor.match(/function(?=[^}]*value\s?:\s?(\w+))/im)[1]
```

I have a list of the different properties I want to lift, for example label and id so I iterate through them and dynamically set my regex using `RegExp`.

```
// Iterate through id, label, value
for(var prop in obj) {
 var propRegex = new RegExp('/function(?=[^}]*' + prop + '\\s?:\\s?(\\w+))/im');
 var propValue = valueAccessor.match(propRegex)[1];
}
```

Although the propRegex source is identical to the structure in the first example, it returns `undefined` and thus means I can't extract the relative values.

Can anybody explain the difference between the two and where I am going wrong?

Comment: `new RegExp(pattern, flags);`

Comment: The `/` are the **delimiters** of the regex literal, just like `"` are the delimiters of a string. They tell the parser where the pattern starts and ends. They are not part of the value (pattern) itself. If you don't use a regex literal, don't put `/` around the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

It is

```
new RegExp(pattern, flags);
```

so you need to drop the `/` and move the `im` out

```
var propRegex = new RegExp('function(?=[^}]*' + prop + '\\s?:\\s?(\\w+))', 'im');
```

Reference: [MDN RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Will accept the answer in a second, I haven't really used Regex to a high level in Javascript so I think I got a bit confused because I didn't specify any flags in the original `string.match` (even though there is an overload)

Comment: Felix Kling's comment has just kicked in... I understand now. When Stack lets me accept I will, cheers for that - had me caught for a while now! :P

Comment: The regex is also needlessly complicated, even though it works. There's no need for the lookahead: `'function[^}]*' + prop + '\\s?:\\s?(\\w+)'`. Perhaps he meant to use a non-capturing group instead `(?:  )`.

Comment: @BrianStephens I despise Regex! I spoke to one of our "regex guru's" in the office for this, I am sure he will be pleased to have your feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your RegExp below is not well formed.

Try doing:

```
for(var prop in obj) {
 var propRegex = new RegExp("function(?=[^}]*" + prop + "\\s?:\\s?(\\w+))", "im");
 var propValue = valueAccessor.match(propRegex)[1];
}
```

Comment: That would literally look for `+ prop +` inside the string, which is certainly not what the OP wants.

Comment: I forgot to change the single quotes inside the RegExp. I changed the first and last one (cause i prefer using double quotes) but forgot to change the others.

Comment: That's why it's always good to properly explain the problem and solution ;) Otherwise it's hard to tell what you changed to solve the problem and what might just be a typo.